# is their a way with unitless line-height to be logarithmic?

Tags: html, css

with a font of 16px, i need a line-height of around 26px (around 10px of white space between 2 lines of text), so i set

body {
  line-height:1.6
  font-size:16px
}

Now the problem if in child elements i increase the font-size to for exemple 50px (title for exemple), then i will have a line height of 80px that mean around 30px of white space between 2 lines that is visually too much.

so is their a way to specify the line-height to be logarithmic ? more bigger the font is, more little the line height is ?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with an example what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not with CSS. You would need javascript to do that. The permitted line height values don't include that sort of mathematical function.